# CSS only responsive menu not closed on page load

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, response, nav

I am using a **css only** responsive menu, unfortunately the environment I am working in doesn't support javascript.

```css
.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}

/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

/* 48em = 768px */

@media (min-width: 81.25em) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
  <ul class="menu">   
    <li class="">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="#">Link 5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="#">Link 6</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

The issue I am facing is that if I resize the browser to show the responsive menu (with hamburger icon) and then click on link 3, when this page loads the responsive menu is still open when it should be closed (collapsed). This happens for any of the links using the same css and HTML for the menu.

Also after some testing this only seems to be an issue in the latest version of chrome and safari, IE and firefox loads ok.

Any ideas where I could be going wrong please? I will mention again, that I am unable to use any javascript or jQuery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a CSS-only solution, try using the checkbox hack. Basically, the idea is to use a checkbox and assign different styles based on whether the box is checked or not used the :checked pseudo selector. The checkbox can be hidden, if need be, by attaching it to a label.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, but the snippet above uses the checkbox hack already.